# How to reduce the number of features in text classification?

Tags: python, nlp, text-classification, naivebayes, countvectorizer

I'm doing dialect text classification and I'm using countVectorizer with naive bayes. The number of features are too many, I have collected 20k tweets with 4 dialects. every dialect have 5000 tweets. And the total number of features are 43K. I was thinking maybe that's why I could be having overfitting. Because the accuracy has dropped a lot when I tested on new data. So how can I fix the number of features to avoid overfitting the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the parameter **max_features** to 5000 for instance, It might help with overfitting. You could also tinker with **max_df** (for instance set it to 0.95)

Comment: @JohnSall Have you tried with different values, have you plotted the validation accuracy as a function of the dimensions ?

Comment: because after every change of feature, I have retrain it again and find the accuracy. So all of that has to be in a for loop?

Answer (score 1):

This drop on test data is caused by [curse of dimensionality](https://medium.com/diogo-menezes-borges/give-me-the-antidote-for-the-curse-of-dimensionality-b14bce4bf4d2). You can use some dimensionality reduction method to reduce this effect. Possible choice is Latent Semantic Analysis implemented in [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html).

Comment: I tried TruncatedSVD, after I did the truncation, it gave me an error when I wanted to train it.